# How do I receive the context parameter in the a cloud function onCall?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is called by my front-side app in React Native. Here is my cloud function:

```
exports.listProducts = functions.https.onCall((temp, context) => {
  console.log("fired");
  return context;
});
```

And here is how I call the function:

```
    let temp = await functions().httpsCallable("listProducts")(
      null,
      firebase.auth().currentUser
    );
```

However, I can't acccess the context variable in my cloud function which according to docs should be the Firebase auth. And the console.log in that function does not give me a log.

Answer (score 1):

Any parameters you pass to the callable function are available in the first parameter, which you call `temp`, but that the Firebase documentation refers to as `data`.

You don't need to pass the current user to the callable function yourself, as the Firebase SDK already handles that for you, and the server already decoded the current user into `context.auth`.

For more on both parameters and the `auth` context, have a look at the Firebase documentation on [writing and deploying callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function), which contains:

> Use functions.https.onCall to create an HTTPS callable function. This method takes two parameters: data, and optional context:
>
> ```
> // Saves a message to the Firebase Realtime Database but sanitizes the text by removing swearwords.
> exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
>  // ...
> });
> ```
>
> For a callable function that saves a text message to the Realtime Database, for example, data could contain the message text, while context parameters represent user auth information:
>
> ```
> // Message text passed from the client.
> const text = data.text;
> // Authentication / user information is automatically added to the request.
> const uid = context.auth.uid;
> const name = context.auth.token.name || null;
> const picture = context.auth.token.picture || null;
> const email = context.auth.token.email || null;
> ```

Comment: Ok now I understand context being generated for me, so when making the change to my function call: `let temp = await functions().httpsCallable("listProducts")(null);`, and having my cloud function as `exports.listProducts = functions.https.onCall((temp, context) => {return context.auth;});`, I'm getting a return value of {"data": null}. So it doesn't appear context is equal to any value.

Comment: From that result it seems that you're returning the `data`, and not the `context`.

Comment: It seems like it but I’m explicitly returning in my listProducts cloud function: ‘context.auth’. And when I console log the result, that is what I’m getting.

Comment: I checked again, and I am indeed returning the context.auth variable and getting a result of null. What I enter as `data` when calling the cloud function does not affect the null result.

Comment: I actually think you probably can't return the entire `context`, as the return value of a callable cloud function has to be a plain JSON object. So I recommend returning just the UID (or whatever you need for this use-case).

Comment: I see, I just tried using `return context.auth.uid;` in my cloud function, and the response I'm receiving is: "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 5): Error:INTERNAL Error: INTERNAL"